# How to embed widget written by vue into a vue webapp

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a website with Vuejs. I have the code like this

*app.js*

```
new Vue({
  el: '.page-wrapper',
  ...
})
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <!-- content-->
    </div>
</body>
```

Now I want to embed a widget which is built by Vuejs like

```
<div id="widget"></div>
<script src="https://widget.com/widget.js"></script>
```

inside `page-wrapper` class.
I've tried to put the `script` tag outside the origin Vue component but the content of widget still did not render.

I'm new to Vuejs, could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to take a stab at this...

**index.html**

```
<div id="app">
    <my-widget></my-widget>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://widget.com/widget.js></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
Vue.component('my-widget', {
    template: '<div id="widget"></div>'
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

My Vue instance is `#app` and I'm loading your `widget.js` asset in `index.html`. I'm probably completely underestimating this, apologies if that's the case!

Comment: Still not work. I find a solution is splitting `new Vue()` into many Vue component

Comment: you have to create a new div element in the widget and add vue to that element. .you can't reply on adding it the parent #app div